# How to say "Get well soon!"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

Salvete! My friend who loves Latin is sick and I want to tell him "Get well soon!" in Latin.
Is *sanesco* the right verb to use here? Should I use the present or the future imperative (mox sanesce/sanescito)?

Gratias vobis ago!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verb *sanescere* sounds good, although it seems to be quite rare. (What do I have to read in Lewis & Short? *Post-Augustan?* Fie!) The usual term is *convalescere*. You can say *mox sanesce* for sure, but it sounds a bit like an overly literal translation, does it not? I would prefer something like:

> Fac quam primum convalescas.
> *Please recover as soon as possible.*

On the other hand, your Latin loving friend might appreciate it if you went for a full-blown Cicero quote like this ([Epistulae ad familiares 16,11](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/fam16.shtml#leleven)):

> Modo fac, id quod est humanitatis tuae, ne quid aliud cures hoc tempore, nisi ut quam commodissime convalescas.
> *I only ask – you owe it to your humanity – that you do nothing else now but take care that you recover as fully as possible.*